# How to check if two matrices have the same column space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the two matrices :
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
1& 2\\
3 & 6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

> How do I check if they have the same column space?

they do not seem to have the same echelon form,

Comment: What is the column space of each matrix?

Comment: Hello! do you know the definition of column space? Note that two matrices have same column space if the obtained column-reduced echelon form preserves the dimension of the matrix so if each matrix have the same **column-reduced** echelon form then they  have same column space

Answer (score 0):

The echelon form is obtained by performing operations on rows, but you're interested in columns. So you do something similar - you take the transpose, then perform the row operations to bring your matrices into echelon form, and check if you get the same thing. The two matrices will have the same column space if and only if their transpose will have the same **reduced** echelon form (up to possible rows of zeros, if the matrices are not of the same size).